# How to remove a created image in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, onclick, picturebox

I have it so the user can click on an image view and drag the item elsewhere on the form, doing this creates a new image whilst the original image box stays put. How would I delete one of the duplicated images on click?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var dragImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
            DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            DestroyIcon(icon);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnGiveFeedback(GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
    }
    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap))) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap));
        var pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap));
        pb.Size = pb.Image.Size;
        pb.Location = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X - pb.Width / 2, e.Y - pb.Height / 2));
        this.Controls.Add(pb);
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the delete operation after the drag drop.

```
        protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e) {
        var pb = new PictureBox {
            Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap))
        };
        pb.Size = pb.Image.Size;
        pb.Location = PointToClient(new Point(e.X - pb.Width / 2, e.Y - pb.Height / 2));
        Controls.Add(pb);
        // deletion here: Controls.Remove(pictureBox1 or pb);
        base.OnDragDrop(e);
    }
```

If you wish to delete it somewhere else, you will need to declare a variable at class level, and assign it with 'pb'. Then you will can decide which one to delete given both pictureBox1 and pb.